# T-SQL insert static values into resultant set from another joined query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

I need to insert 2 values into a table based on other tables' select results.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT M.DNUM, M.NAME, U.ID, A.ID, A.RIGHT
    FROM [ACCESS] A JOIN [MASTER] M
    ON M.DNUM = A.NUM
    JOIN [USERS] U
    ON U.NUM = D.ID
    WHERE M.ALIAS = '0-50'
    GROUP BY M.DNUM, M.NAME, U.ID, A.ID, A.RIGHT
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [ACCESS]
    (ID, RIGHT)
    VALUES
    ('9','3')
END
```

I need to add the 2 values to the `[ACCESS]` table but only want to add the values if `M.ALIAS` is 0-50 AND if `A.NUM = M.NUM`.

When I ran the script it completed without error but insert did not happen when I recheck.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ´only want to add the values if M.ALIAS is 0-50 AND if A.NUM = M.NUM´ You are doing `IF NOT EXISTS` which is the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Add `ELSE` clause with `PRINT` to test `IF` condition